# Android Studio is keep on executing gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, osx-yosemite

I am using android studio for a long time now(from 0.4).Recently I have updated my Mac to `Yosemite.`I am using latest android studio.

If I open my previous project, Android studio will stuck in `Gradle` Executing task and never complete the build though some time it does build but in more then 20 minutes. But if create a new project on my studio it will build properly.
My old project build properly on other system.

**From the past two days I am looking for a solution but could not find any.
Please Help!**

Logs from Android Studio.

```
------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,487 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1641136, 11 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,487 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.10.1, x86_64) 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,487 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716 (Apple Inc.) 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,487 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 20.65-b04-466.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,509 [     50]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=NoJavaDistribution -Didea.home.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents -Didea.executable=studio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,553 [     94]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 44 ms 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,596 [    137]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 43 ms 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,596 [    137]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - 2015-01-12 15:18:39 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: /var/folders/13/44ynsdyx0jdgyz3ghh8z2y580000gn/T/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio

2015-01-12 15:18:40,601 [    142]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2015-01-12 15:18:40,602 [    143]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/13/44ynsdyx0jdgyz3ghh8z2y580000gn/T/intellij-shell-env8711749495723824362.tmp' 
2015-01-12 15:18:41,110 [    651]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (15 vars) 
2015-01-12 15:18:42,855 [   2396]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2015-01-12 15:18:43,920 [   3461]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 21 plugins initialized in 1610 ms 
2015-01-12 15:18:43,921 [   3462]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.0.1), CVS Integration (11), Commander (1.0.0), Copyright (8.1), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-01-12 15:18:44,477 [   4018]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=756744192 
2015-01-12 15:18:44,571 [   4112]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2015-01-12 15:18:44,589 [   4130]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-01-12 15:18:45,219 [   4760]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2015-01-12 15:18:46,636 [   6177]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:18:46,655 [   6196]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:18:47,819 [   7360]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:18:47,821 [   7362]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 85 application components initialized in 3888 ms 
2015-01-12 15:18:47,861 [   7402]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 7997 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:19,896 [  39437]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-01-12 15:19:19,901 [  39442]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-01-12 15:19:20,055 [  39596]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dynamic.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:20,199 [  39740]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 139 project components initialized in 768 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:20,560 [  40101]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 12 module(s) loaded in 361 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:20,627 [  40168]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/customization.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:20,686 [  40227]   WARN - j.ui.mac.MacMainFrameDecorator - no url bundle present. 
To use platform protocol handler to open external links specify required protocols in the mac app layout section of the build file
Example: args.urlSchemes = ["your-protocol"] will handle following links: your-protocol://open?file=file&line=line 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,012 [  40553]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,012 [  40553]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,017 [  40558]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 24 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,017 [  40558]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,313 [  40854]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,713 [  41254]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "192.168.9.254".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,730 [  41271]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "192.168.9.254".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,812 [  41353]   INFO - .roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl - Directory index initialized in 0 ms, indexed 0 directories 
2015-01-12 15:19:21,980 [  41521]   INFO - pl.PushedFilePropertiesUpdater - File properties pushed in 164 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:22,531 [  42072]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2015-01-12 15:19:22,930 [  42471]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/codeStyleSettings.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:22,932 [  42473]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/projectCodeStyle.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:22,972 [  42513]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/fileColors.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:23,223 [  42764]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/gradle.settings.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:24,991 [  44532]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix jar:file:/Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/lib/resources.jar!/artwork/toolWindowProject_AS.png 
2015-01-12 15:19:26,053 [  45594]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/gant_config.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:26,164 [  45705]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 3824 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:26,164 [  45705]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2015-01-12 15:19:26,165 [  45706]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 1 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:28,693 [  48234]   INFO - nject.config.XPathSupportProxy - XPath Support is not available 
2015-01-12 15:19:28,748 [  48289]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/IntelliLang.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:29,654 [  49195]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2015-01-12 15:19:29,654 [  49195]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestSupportsInput 
2015-01-12 15:19:33,805 [  53346]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/remote-servers.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:34,116 [  53657]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 14717 ms 
2015-01-12 15:19:40,193 [  59734]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/intentionSettings.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:44,052 [  63593]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/checker.xml file is null 
2015-01-12 15:19:45,960 [  65501]   INFO - dea.ddms.adb.AdbService$Ddmlib - DDMLib initialized 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,548 [  69089]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,575 [  69116]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,686 [  69227]   INFO - dle.util.AndroidGradleSettings - Found Android SDK home at '/Applications/sdk' (from local.properties file) 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,686 [  69227]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - Build JVM args: [] 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,689 [  69230]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Maven repo at '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository' 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,764 [  69305]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1' 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,764 [  69305]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, /private/var/folders/13/44ynsdyx0jdgyz3ghh8z2y580000gn/T/asLocalRepo6286008561669474057.gradle] 
2015-01-12 15:19:49,771 [  69312]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, /private/var/folders/13/44ynsdyx0jdgyz3ghh8z2y580000gn/T/asLocalRepo6286008561669474057.gradle] 
2015-01-12 15:23:20,310 [ 279851]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "192.168.9.254".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2015-01-12 15:26:55,407 [ 494948]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "192.168.9.254".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2015-01-12 15:30:06,745 [ 686286]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "192.168.9.254".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2015-01-12 15:33:58,615 [ 918156]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - You have JVM property "socksProxyHost" set to "192.168.9.254".
This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy
This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.

(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.)
```

Comment: Gradle might have been updated in between, some key words were changed. It's probably best to generate new ones and migrate the important stuff to them block by block.

Comment: @G_V: I can not migrate because of git.I will loose all the history and tracks.

Comment: Then I don't really know what to tell you. I had several projects in 0.8 that absolutely broke down with 0.8.14 on the gradle. It went from 0.3 to 1 overnight iirc, which changed a bunch of things like several key words and the structure of gradle files. I don't see how git affects the rest of your project though, since it's just the build files for which you create a new version.